# onEnterAnimationComplete() not called API 21

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I am using shared element transition between activities and on devices with API 21 the method onEnterAnimationComplete() is not called. Is says [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onEnterAnimationComplete()) that it was introduced in api 21. 
Note that the method get called for Android version6 and 7. The problem occurs only for devices running on Android 5. Any ideas?

Comment: I have been using that callback too and it seems to be working just fine on devices that run API 22 and above. On API 21 it seems that sometimes it's not getting called and sometimes it's called. I haven't been abl to find out why but for the moment i added my code in the onResume of the activity instead of that callback.